# CreateFileMapping fails when 64-bit application reaches 2GB

Tags: c#, winapi, memory, memory-management

I have a 64-bit application WPF/C# which allocates memory using CreateFileMapping()
the function returns error 1455 once I hit 2GB limit.

My machine has 32GB RAM and page file is disabled.
Can it be the CreateFileMapping(win32 API) works only on 32 bit?

```
_byteCount = (uint)((_stride) * height * ((short)bpp).NumberOfBytes());

 ColorFileMapping = CreateFileMapping(new IntPtr(-1), IntPtr.Zero, 0x04, 0, _byteCount, null);
```

Comment: Disabled page file looks to be the key factor here - "The paging file is too small for this operation to complete.". Under normal conditions (with page file) even 32-bit app can create file mappings beyond 2 and 4 GB (it's mapping the views which is subject to 32-bit address space limitations).

Comment: I agree with @RomanR. - when I use large MMFs, it's always necessary to back it with a temp file, otherwise the system paging gets hammered. It's easy enough to create a temp file that gets deleted on close, so there's little additional code involved.

Comment: @RogerRowland I have changed the page file to a large size and indeed I managed to allocate more images. Could you elaborate more about MMF?

Comment: `CreateFileMapping` creates a memory mapped file (MMF), which is disk space mapped to appear in the process address space and managed by the OS. If you specify `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` (i.e. -1) as the first argument, the mapping is backed by the system page file. Instead, you can `CreateFile` a temporary file, of the required size and pass the file handle to `CreateFileMapping`, which will cure your problem (assuming enough disk space is free).

Comment: @RogerRowland Really appreciate the help. I think this is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

_byteCount should be of type DWORD to avoid overflow of uint.